# Playing a video at first boot after OEM install?

Tags: boot, system-installation, oem

Just wanted to know if it is possible to play a video at the first boot, after installing with the OEM option? I have prepared a laptop for a friend, and would like to flash a little eye candy at the first boot :P
- Hope someone can help!

Video example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B2if2K7gZpY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place a script in the `/etc/init.d` directory like such:

```
#!/bin/bash

totem /path/to/file
sleep 120
# 120 is the number of seconds you think the video will run for
rm $0
```

Save this in say `~/welcome.sh`.
`chmod +x ~/welcome.sh`
`sudo cp ~/welcome.sh /etc/init.d/welcome.sh`

/etc/init.d is the place where all startup scripts may be placed.
`totem` is the name of the default video player on Ubuntu.
`rm $0` will remove the file we just wrote so that it runs only once.